# Postgres HAVING ilike any wildcard in array_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a filter where the inputted value is similar to any value in an aggregate, using ilike and wildcard. My attempt of query so far is

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_agg(vo.name)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_variation pv
ON p.id = pv.product_id
LEFT JOIN variation_option vo
ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING $1 ilike any(array_agg('%' || vo.name || '%'));
```

but it doesn't work.

It gets even more complicated, because ideally Id be able to input an array of strings, where any of them are similar to the aggregate. Any tips?

Comment: You query does what I thought it would do.  I don't know what **you** thought it would do, so "doesn't work" doesn't mean anything to me.  Please describe in more detail, or provide example data and expected output.

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gepe719Rxntu4WnWVeGsLh/0

Comment: @jjanes Oh, I realize now whats wrong. This is more like what I did https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cwxyd8DFMMANiHXRfVhcvf/0. I expected for it to match if `thin` was inputted, but since the wildcard isn't on the inputted value that won't match. This would be a lookahead so the solution wouldn't work

Comment: I don't understand the intention behind the left joins.  Are they really necessary?

Comment: I think so? It's linking each product to it's variations, and filtering them by the variations

Comment: But if no variation exists, how can it survive the filter?

Comment: I stripped this query a bit to focus in the having statement, but the user can also filter by product name, if no variation exists I still want to be able to query for products without variation

Answer (score 0):

from the query you wrote, i understand that what you want is something like this:

"list all products with all of their variation options, but only if at least one of those variation option names include the parameter $1"

if so, my approach to this query would be;

```
WITH
    "options" AS (
        SELECT "id" FROM "variation_option" WHERE "name" ILIKE '%' || %1 || '%'
    )
SELECT
     p."id"
    ,p."name"
    ,ARRAY_AGG( vo."name" ) AS "variation_options"
FROM
    "product" AS p
    LEFT JOIN "product_variation" AS pv ON pv."product_id" = p."id"
    LEFT JOIN "variation_option" AS vo ON vo."id" = pv."variation_option_id"
GROUP BY
    p."id"
HAVING
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM "options" WHERE "id" = ANY( ARRAY_AGG( vo."id" ) ) LIMIT 1 )
```

lets check what we're doing with this query;

1. we collect the "id"s of all the possible options in the first query of CTE (WITH-Queries or Common Table Expression, for details of this syntax; [the documents are here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) which is named as "options"
2. in the HAVING section, we're checking aggregated option names from main query against our "options" collection

---

in the other hand we can write a simpler query, if use aggregated options names not as an array but a string;

```
SELECT
     p."id"
    ,p."name"
    ,ARRAY_AGG( vo."name" ) AS "variation_options"
FROM
    "product" AS p
    LEFT JOIN "product_variation" AS pv ON pv."product_id" = p."id"
    LEFT JOIN "variation_option" AS vo ON vo."id" = pv."variation_option_id"
GROUP BY
    p."id"
HAVING
    ARRAY_AGG( vo."name" )::VARCHAR ILIKE '%' || %1 || '%'
```

Comment: The wildcard must go on the RHS, so what you have there is literal percent signs.

Comment: yep, wildcards go on right hand side like jjanes said

Comment: thanks!! you're right! my previous answer was completely wrong. i guess i wasn't wake enough. now edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could define the reverse operation of ilike, similar to [as described](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228235/match-string-pattern-to-any-array-element/228262#228262) (that is for LIKE rather than ILIKE, but same principle).  But if the ultimate goal is to have arrays on both sides of the operator, I don't think this really helps as it gets you one step of the way but then leaves you at a dead end.

So I would impose the filter before aggregating, something like.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_agg(vo.name)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_variation pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
LEFT JOIN variation_option vo ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
where p.id in (
   SELECT p.id
   FROM product p 
   JOIN product_variation pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
   JOIN variation_option vo ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
   where vo.name ilike any ARRAY['%thin%']
)
GROUP BY p.id
```

The single-element array is just for future expansion since you indicated you would want it.  This also might potentially benefit from a `pg_trgm` index on vo.name, which your current formulation cannot.